# What is an explicit homeomorphism between cubes $[0,1]^n$ and $[a,b]^n$

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity, proof-writing, compactness

I wish to show that $[a,b]^n$ is compact **just using** the result that $[0,1]^n$ is compact.

In $\mathbb{R}$, we can construct an explicit homeomorphism between $[0,1]$ and $[a,b]$ via $f(x) = (b-a)x+a$, this allows us to establish any closed interval is compact.

Now I wish to demonstrate that any closed cube is compact. Is there a quick homeomorphism we can establish between $[0,1]^n$ and $[a,b]^n$?

If not, is there a easier way to show that $[a,b]^n$ is compact, knowing that $[0,1]^n$ is compact?

Comment: The continuous image of a compact is compact. You just need to find a continuous map sending $[0,1]^n$ to $[a,b]^n$ (i.e. you do not need to worry about your map being a homeomorphism or not)

Comment: What is an explicit homeomorphism between intervals $[0,1 ]$ and $[a,b ]?$

Comment: I'm wondering, what's the motivation? closed and bounded not easy enough for $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: You will need a different method of proof for the case $a > b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the map 
$$f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=\left((b-a)x_1+a,\ldots,(b-a)x_n+a\right).$$
This is a continuous map of $[0,1]^n$ *onto* $[a,b]^n$ (in fact it is a homeomorphism,but this is unnecessary), and since you know $[0,1]^n$ is compact, it follows that $f([0,1]^n)=[a,b]^n$ is compact.

Comment: So what if $a > b$?

Comment: @RobArthan then you wouldn't use the notation $[a,b]$.

Comment: $[a, b] = \emptyset$ when $a > b$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics).

Comment: @RobArthan That's rather pedantic.  I think it's understood from context that the OP meant $b>a$.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if $\phi: A \rightarrow B$ is a homeomorphism, then we have a homeomorphism $\Psi:A^n \rightarrow B^n$, where $\Psi( \mathbf{x} ) = (\phi(x_1), \phi(x_2), ..., \phi(x_n))$.

So, if you've already found a homeomorphism $[0, 1] \rightarrow [a, b]$, this fact finishes your proof.  On the other hand, it isn't hard to just naively construct a homeomorphism/continuous function $[0, 1]^n \rightarrow [a, b]^n$ as others suggest.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lambda(t_1, \ldots, t_n).(a(1-t_1) + bt_1, \ldots, a(1-t_n)+bt_n) : [0, 1]^n \to [a, b]^n$$

Comment: ...what is that?

Comment: lambda expression

Comment: @Kaa1el: I've reformatted your answer: we like mathematics to look like mathematics on MSE. I hope I didn't introduce any errors. $\ddot{\smile}$.

Comment: this looks much better! thanks!